# What tax laws apply to Meetup group income?

Tags: united-states, taxes

If a Meetup.com group, a.k.a. a simple local community group, has a small fee on its events, and magically begins to accumulate tens of thousands of dollars, what laws are applicable to that income and the subsequent use of it? It's neither a business or an individual, technically...

The money is all deposited in the Meetup account via Paypal transactions. This is all in the United States.

Comment: Who controls it, who collects it, who holds it, who spends it?  Any chance the group is formally incorporated or certified under state law?  Or is this really a question about meetup.com policies and you are just asking what WOULD happen?

Comment: Who is depositing the money? Or does it just stay cash? Because whoever/whatever deposits the cash will likely be the one on the hook for taxes

Comment: Deposits it where? These are all paypal transactions.

Comment: Paypal to whose name? That guy is going to see a 1099 if the amount exceeds $600/yr. And he better have the paper trail to account for it.

Comment: For which tax jurisdiction?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I don't believe the $600/yr 1099-MISC applies in this case, since PayPal doesn't "employ" or pay the payees, they just move money around. As far as I know, you have to have $20,000+ in volume from 200+ transactions in the calendar year before PayPal will report income / issue documents, and that will be a 1099-K, and that's all bound under IRS Section 6050W

Comment: @Noah - a Q&A on PayPal's site confirms your comment. I appreciate you setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

Those Meetup members who pay to attend an event are not forming a partnership. Just like if they bought a Concert Ticket - no partnership can be forced upon them as it is fee for service.

But, those Organizers who are controlling the funds by collecting and/or depositing them, or using equivalent value collected in some other form are either 1) Sole Proprietors, or 2) possible Partners with other Organizers or Members who are sharing the collection of the Fees, or 3) are possibly Not For Profit Orgs under IRC 501(c)(social/fraternal/other orgs depending on function) who are not in compliance unless they filed for a Tax Exemption. If they are not operating under a Tax Exemption Letter, the Net Income (after expenses) gets taxed to the Organizer(s) who control the Fee events revenues.

Mostly all Meetup activities that charge fees are incurring expenses, therefore, there will be a net income or loss. If a "loss" it is usually not deductible under the IRC 183 Hobby Loss Rules.

Comment: Good answer but the self promotion is not allowed. You should put the link in your bio, or if you want even change your username to that. That is an allowed form of self-promotion.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I thought that "does not disclose the author's affiliation" was what caused it to be spam (and he certainly disclosed his affiliation).

Answer (score 0):

In the United States tax law, a group of people who are neither an individual nor an incorporated entity is called "[partnership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partnership)".

Here's [the IRS page on partnerships](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Partnerships).

Income derived by such a "meetup.com" group is essentially a partnership income with the group members being the partners.

However, as you can see from the questions in the comments, the situation can become significantly more complex if this partnership is not managed properly.